# Text displayed as hieroglyphs on website

Tags: browser

On my mobile browsers, the text just shows up as hieroglyphs in [this site](http://core-darmstadt.de). The menu items also do not show up as well.

Does any one have ideas where this comes from?

Screenshots (click to enlarge):

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: (1) What Android version are you on? (2) Are you using stock ROM? Or custom ROM?

Comment: Text is readable on my Samsung Galaxy S2, running CyanogenMod 10.1

Comment: (1)(2) no idea. i just got a hint from the customer and looked it up on http://www.browserstack.com. The thing is the text problem is one thing, but the disappearing of the menu item another which could not be a text-problem i think.

Comment: Does your screenshot come from an emulator? Or is that an actual Samsung Galaxy S2? Browserstack? [yes, I noticed you mentioned that, but I'm not familiar with BrowserStack]

Comment: Just an emulator, but people who have an actual device told me about both errors.

Comment: And are you the developer of that website?

Comment: The menu is also black for me.

Comment: yes i am. thats why i am asking. on all devices i tested the site the menu problem and the font problem did not appear.

Comment: In that case, this question should be moved to StackOverflow.com. Programming / Development-related issues are not discussed in Android.se. I will flag this question for move to StackOverflow.com :)

Comment: nobody is answering there. so i thought it might be an android problem. thats why i posted it here.

Comment: Probably has something to do with your CSS or JavaScript. I think you probably should describe in StackOverflow the code / libraries you are using.

Comment: Although this question is asked from a developer who sees this problem, I don't think that we should close it as off-topic as a user could ask the same question.

Comment: @Flow Point taken. The answer would most likely be development- / implementation-related though.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a lack of font support on the device.

On my Nexus 7 I see this:

[image: Site on Nexus 7]

Comment: this is ok. i mean the site takes Arial. Just have to reset the font size. but on the other on i posted its not even a font, even if i activate Arial only.

Comment: @Max it is device and Android version dependant sorry!